# Unable to delete keys in JSON

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I have the following JSON:

```
{
  "root" : {
    "111111" : {
      "sampleKey" : true
    },
    "222222" : {
      "sampleKey" : false
    },
    "333333" : {
      "sampleKey" : true
    },
    "444444" : {
      "sampleKey" : false
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to delete any element whose **sampleKey** is **false** and then save the updated JSON file, but my code doesn't work and I am trying to figure out what am I doing wrong:

```
import json

output_file = open('input_file.json').read()
output_json = json.loads(output_file)

for i in xrange(len(output_json["root"])):
    if(output_json["root"][i]["signedUp"] == "false"):
        output_json.pop(output_json[i])
        break

open("updated-file.json", "w").write(json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
)
```

Can someone help me

Comment: `output_json["root"]` is a dictionary and you're indexing it with integers!

Comment: Note that output_json is a Python dict.  Values of `true` and `false` in the original JSON file will now be Python boolean values `True` and `False`. In addition to the comments about referencing the dict values (Kasramvd's answer is great), be aware of the data types you're using. All your items will fail the `== "false"` test because you are comparing booleans and strings.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `output_json["root"]` is a dictionary and you're indexing it with integers. Secondly as a more pythonic way you better to iterate over your items and just keep the needed ones:

```
new_dict = {key: value for key, value in output_json["root"].items() if value['sampleKey']}
```

If all of your items doesn't have `sampleKey` you can use `dict.get()` instead of direct indexing.

```
new_dict = {key: value for key, value in output_json["root"].items() 
            if value.get('sampleKey', True)}
```

Comment: I want to keep them as JSON in the same structure as the original file, just want the unneeded elements to be gone. I ran your code but it says: `KeyError: 'sampleKey'`

Comment: @SomeAndroidProgrammar, probably, not all of your sub-dictionaries have ot

Comment: @SomeAndroidProgrammar as volcano said * probably, not all of your sub-dictionaries have it*.

Answer (score 1):

You'r root is a dict not a list so you may not use integer indexes . Here is updated code that works

```
import json

output_json = json.load(open('input_file.json'))
for key in output_json["users"].keys():
    if(not output_json["users"][key].get("signedUp",True)):
        print "deleting",key
        del(output_json["users"][key])

json.dump(output_json,open('updated-file.json','w'))
```

**PS:** In your example you metioned `sampleKey` instead of `signedUp`

Comment: Never compare to _False_! Use _if not_

Comment: Not better still. Use boolean operators, for god's sake!

Comment: `is False` makes it explicit  for the question here. It reads `whose sampleKey is false`

Comment: You make me suspect that you don't fully understand how _if_ works. You are writing redundant code!

Comment: Downvoted for adding unnecessary "decorators" to boolean test

Comment: Python, use _not_ operator

Comment: @volcano ,that was a stupid mistake agreed :D. Updated

Comment: @someandroidprogrammar That is because in your file there is a `dict` without this key updated the code to handle that

Answer (score 0):

The other maybe you can refer it.

```
output_json['root'] = {x: output_json['root'][x] for x in output_json['root'] if output_json['root'][x]['sampleKey']}
```

I think this is simpler than your way.

Answer (score -2):

Try changing:

```
output_json.pop(output_json[i])
```

to:

```
output_json.pop(i)
```